# many models grouped modelr::add_predictions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to use data labeled as `train` to fit a model then use data labeled as `test` to predict new values. I would like to do this in a "[many models](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html)" scenario.

The following is my current set up. My problem is that I am training and adding predictions to all of the data. I don't know how to discriminate using `modelr`

```
library(modelr)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

# nest data by continent and label test/train data
nested_gap <- gapminder %>% 
  mutate(test_train = ifelse(year < 1992, "train", "test")) %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  nest()

# make a linear model function
cont_model <- function(df) {
  lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df)
}

# fit a model and add predictions to all data
fitted_gap <- nested_gap %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, cont_model)) %>% 
  mutate(pred  = map2(data, model, add_predictions))
```

Comment: in your `cont_model` function, add `data = df %>% filter(test_train == "train")` to get it to build the `lm` only off of the appropriate time period.

Comment: @shuckle thanks, but how to I make predictions off of the test data using the model fit with the training data.

Comment: each of those `lm`'s will be fit with the training data only. the `add_predictions` step will make predictions for both the `train` and `test` values.

Comment: @shuckle I think I understand what you are saying now. Since the data used is only training data then when I pass `model` and `data` to `add_predictions` I will see predictions based off of only the training model. The last step would be to filter only `test` observations.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution provided by @shuckle

```
library(modelr)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

# nest data by continent and label test/train data
nested_gap <- gapminder %>% 
  mutate(test_train = ifelse(year < 1992, "train", "test")) %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  nest()

# make a linear model function than only trains on training set
cont_model <- function(df) {
  lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df %>% filter(test_train == "train"))
}

# fit a model and add predictions to all data
fitted_gap <- nested_gap %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, cont_model)) %>% 
  mutate(pred  = map2(data, model, add_predictions))

# unnest predictions and filter only the test rows
fitted_gap %>% 
  unnest(pred) %>% 
  filter(test_train == "test")
```